# Update localstorage object value & save it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Update localstorage object value & save it using jquery?

Below is the code which I have tried

```js
var cachekey = "shop/elasticCache/sku$$" + this.product.parentSku
const { category } = JSON.parse(
  localStorage.getItem("shop/elasticCache/sku$$" + this.product.parentSku)
)
var productcache = []
productcache = localStorage.getItem(cachekey)
var updatedproductcache = JSON.parse(productcache)
updatedproductcache.name = category
productcache = JSON.stringify(updatedproductcache)
localStorage.setItem(cachekey, productcache)
```

I am trying to update `category` data from localstorage json

Comment: What do you mean by _"using jquery"_

Comment: by using jquery as code

Comment: As far as I know jQuery has no code for manipulating localStorage, and localStorage is very simple to use and doesn't need a library

Comment: i am not sure why local storage is not getting updated

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the non necessary code(repeated code) you will have only this

```
const cachekey = "shop/elasticCache/sku$$" + this.product.parentSku,
  {category} = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(cachekey));
category.name = category;
localStorage.setItem(cachekey, JSON.stringify(category));
```

and although it doesn't make sense, it should work properly, and you need to check for `typeof category !== "undefined"`, maybe it doesn't exist yet in your localStorage